# Image url expires

Tags: theming, media

I've a managed_file field in the custom form, like below

```
$form['image'] = [
      '#type' => 'managed_file',
      '#title' => $this->t('Image'),
      '#description' => t('Image for the item.'),
      '#upload_location' => 'public://basis/',
      '#default_value' => [!empty($values->value) ? $values->value : ''],
      '#states' => [
        'visible' => [
          ':input[name="type"]' => ['value' => 'image'],
        ],
      ],
    ];
```

I'm loading the url like this, This is the build funtion of the block.

```
$values = ImagesListController::keyDetails();
    $logo = $values['footer_logo'];
    $id = $logo['value'];
    $alt = $logo['alt'];

    if (!empty($id)) {
      $details = File::load($id);
      $file = !empty($details) ? $details : '';
    }

    if (!empty($file)) {
      $image = $file->getFileUri();
      $url = ImageStyle::load('header_image')->buildUrl($image);
    }

    return [
      '#theme' => 'allofus_logo_footer',
      '#logo' => !empty($url) ? $url : '',
      '#alt' => !empty($alt) ? $alt : '',
```

In the twig it print for a day or around, then it shows nothing. Why the image is expiring for managed_file in Drupal 8?

In twig

```
<img src="{{ logo }}" alt="{{ alt }}" />
```

Submit function

```
$image = !empty($form_state->hasValue('image')) ? $form_state->getValue('image') : '';

\Drupal::database()
        ->insert('allofus')
        ->fields([
          'value' => $image,
        ])
        ->execute();
      drupal_set_message($this->t('The value has been successfully saved.'));
$response = new RedirectResponse('/admin/add/new');
    $response->send();
```

Comment: I'm guessing you aren't setting the status of the image to FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21file.inc/constant/FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT/8.2.x) when saving the image. You didn't show your submit function though, so that's just an educated guess.

Comment: @Jaypan I've added the submit function. Can you please take a look.

Comment: You need to add $file->setPermanent() in your submit function, then save the file.